# Enabling enhanced measurement programatically

Tags: google-analytics-api

we are using an Admin API to programmatically create Data Streams for given properties - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties.dataStreams/create.

However all of the created Data Streams have enhanced measurement turned off by default. Is there or will there be a possibility to enable it together with the create request?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing a web DataStream? [EnhancedMeasurementSettings](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/EnhancedMeasurementSettings?hl=en) appear to only be for web DataStream's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after a bit of digging

EnhancedMeasurementSettings we can find the following

[EnhancedMeasurementSettings](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/EnhancedMeasurementSettings?hl=en) appear to only be for web DataStream's

> Singleton resource under a WebDataStream, configuring measurement of additional site interactions and content.

The issue being is that this is only listed under alpha1 not the beta version of the api.

Then if we look a bit more we find

[2021-10-12 EnhancedMeasurementSettings methods removed from the API.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/changelog?hl=en#2021-10-12_enhancedmeasurementsettings_methods_removed_from_the_api)

[image]

Which seams to say its being removed but will be added back but its a year later and nothing.

I am going to ping the team and see when it will be added back.

Comment: Thanks a lot, please keep me updated, its important to our automation.

Comment: Hello @Linda Lawton - DaImTo any updated on this please? We would really appreciate this. Thank you

Comment: @iCanLevitate Hi, did you find a way to enable Enhanced Measurement via API?